# How to utilize GPU for/in VNC?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, xorg, vnc, intel-graphics

So I got a server that has an Intel processor featuring an iGPU (Intel Xeon E3-1245 v2) which I want to use. I installed everything so that when I SSH into the machine "vainfo" works - so there is at least something working. Inside the VNC session "vainfo" does not work and applications that I start over the VNC session do not utilize the GPU which I can monitor using "sudo intel_gpu_top" via SSH.
If I run "sudo vainfo" inside the VNC session, it works.

I tried to playback videos in a browser in VNC and it stutters/lags completely, basically the FPS go way down. The CPU usage goes up and the GPU is not working at all.

Now my question is: Is there a way to get this to work or is this simply impossible?
I remember using a VNC connection to another server with a discrete GPU and it worked perfectly via VNC. Barely any CPU usage when playing back videos and that stutter/lag in the VNC connection was barely noticeable. So I'm sure there is a way to do this but I cannot (for days now) figure out what I need to do differently.

I tried different linux distributions, tried different Intel GPU drivers (I figured in the end that I need i965), different VNC applications and different configurations but nothing seems to work. I'm on Debian 11 right now but also tried Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04.

Some stuff I did:

- added the user to the **video** and **render** group
- created a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-intel.conf` file containing

```
Section "OutputClass"
Identifier "Intel"
MatchDriver "i915"
Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

and many other combinations, including setting same in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

- Added `xdg.force_integrated=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and applied using `sudo update-grub`
- Tried the following packages

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-all
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver vainfo
sudo apt-get install libvdpau-va-gl1 i965-va-driver vdpauinfo
```

- Set `VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl`
- Removed `nomodeset` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and applied using `sudo update-grub`

And I mean as vainfo somehow works, I was not unsuccessful in getting the iGPU to generally work or let's say be ready to work but that's it.

The only way I was able to utilize the GPU for a complete desktop and all running apps was using Windows and connecting via RDP but that's not an option, I just wanted to make sure that the iGPU generally works and is not incompatible with the mainboard or disabled in BIOS.

If anybody could guide me in the right direction, that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well there's x11vnc which can be attached to an Xorg server running on real hardware (instead of an Xvfb server or similar). But then it's not exactly a headless solution. There's also the VirtualGL and/or Xpra thing.

Answer (score 3):

> Are you running VNC in service mode?

Virtual Mode sessions are rendered by the CPU and can't use hardware acceleration.

If you need hardware acceleration, try using Service Mode instead:
`sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced --now` and connect on port 5900. 
***Note:*** you will need a connected monitor in most cases for the OS to render the desktop correctly.

In general, if you are looking for performance, ***VNC is not the place to get it.***  Have you tried [X11 forwarding](https://www.quora.com/What-is-X11-forwarding)?  Believe it or not, X windows WAS MADE for seamless forwarding. You should try it.

In your question.. it seems like you might not realize that the speeds that VNC can broadcast is limited by the speed of your your network and that a graphics card can take *very little* advantage of that.

Are you sure this new machine is operating at the network speeds the old was was?

One more addendum to this topic:
The performance differences between these remote technologies is not as black and white as I professed above.  I do not believe my statements to be wrong, but I don't believe them to be absolute either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will make sure to test it asap. The machine is headless, it's a server - so connecting a display is not an option. I wonder why it works so seamlessly in Windows while it's such a pain to get this running on Linux. I also don't really understand if I need to have the VNC connection itself hardware accelerated or just everything inside it. All I want is to have the apps that I start from the VNC session to be hardware accelerated I guess and then keep them on GPU even if I stop the session.

Comment: As I pointed out, please familiarize yourself with X11 forwarding if you are looking for better performance. ***THERE IS NOTHING TO INSTALL.****  VNC takes bitmap regions of the "screen" and sends them across the network.  X11 is faster on linux just like RDC is faster on windows.

Comment: If you're running an OpenGL application on the server and you have an Apple desktop you may (probably will) run into problems with X11 forwarding. With one recent bioinformatics application we had to enable a real X11 server utilizing the GPUs and use turbovnc for the display. Performance was 70-80 frames per second when displaying a protein in high resolution.

Comment: I feel like I don't even completely understand what I need as receiving the image fluently via VNC is not my priority. It's about starting a VNC session, starting the app that plays back the media and that process having hardware acceleration/gpu acceleration. So the main focus should be that the server is running the app as efficient as possible. I'm just coming from the Windows idea that is: Remote Desktop into the machine and as long as the iGPU is active, it will be used for anything I start on the machine. That's what I want for Linux. I don't know if I explained that clearly enough.

Comment: So the VNC should be the "helper" tool that enables me to login to the machine and start a GPU accelerated app but the VNC session itself probably does not need to be accelerated (would be great to see the best possible result) but in the end it's enough that the app/video playback I start on the server is using the iGPU. Hope that makes sense.